# $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty } \left ( 1 - \cos(\frac{1}{n}) \right )$ converges or diverges?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty } \left ( 1 - \cos\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \right )$$

I tried all of the tests but I couldnt solve this.Does it converges or diverges?

Comment: try to use Taylor expansion.

Comment: Minor detail: the series shouldn't startat $n=0$.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint** $\cos x \approx 1-\dfrac{x^2}2$ for small $x$

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $1-\cos{(1/n)} = 2 \sin^2{(1/(2 n))}$.  How does $\sin{x}$ behave as $x \rightarrow 0$?

Once you have that, can you think of a sum that behaves the same as $n \rightarrow \infty$?  Does it converge or diverge?